# Adjust the plot size to full display regardless of the length of y-axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the dataframe below. As you can see there are some really long names in the `BIO` variable.As a result of this my plot is getting smaller while I need to be displayed as big as it may be.

```
BIO<-c('posttranslational protein folding (GO:0051084)posttranslational protein folding (GO:0051084)',"'de novo' protein folding (GO:0006458)",
       'posttranslational protein folding (GO:0051085)',"'de novo' protein folding (GO:0006451)",
       'posttranslational protein folding (GO:0051086)',"'de novo' protein folding (GO:00064582)",
       'posttranslational protein folding (GO:0051087)',"'de novo' protein folding (GO:00064583)",
       'posttranslational protein folding (GO:00510844)',"'de novo' protein folding (GO:00064588)",
       'posttranslational protein folding (GO:00510855)',"'de novo' protein folding (GO:00064511)",
       'posttranslational protein folding (GO:00510866)',"'de novo' protein folding (GO:000645822)",
       'posttranslational protein folding (GO:00510877)',"'de novo' protein folding (GO:000645833)")

FE<-c(5,10,15,20,25,35,10,15,5,10,15,20,25,35,10,15)
FDR<-c(7.67e-05,7.67e-05,7.67e-04,7.67e-03,7.67e-03,7.67e-03,7.67e-02,7.67e-02,
       6.67e-05,8.67e-05,4.67e-05,3.67e-05,3.67e-05,4.67e-05,5.67e-05,6.67e-05 )
d<-data.frame(BIO,FE,FDR)

# Libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


# Most basic bubble plot
d %>%
  arrange(desc(FDR)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=FE, y=BIO, size=FE, color=FDR)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.5) +
  scale_size(range = c(.1, 24), name="Population (M)")
```

[image]

Comment: You can break labels using `\n` (for example `'posttranslational protein folding\n(GO:0051085)'`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest playing with the limits in scale of x-axis using `scale_x_continuous()`. Here and example:

```
BIO<-c('posttranslational protein folding (GO:0051084)posttranslational protein folding (GO:0051084)',"'de novo' protein folding (GO:0006458)",
       'posttranslational protein folding (GO:0051085)',"'de novo' protein folding (GO:0006451)",
       'posttranslational protein folding (GO:0051086)',"'de novo' protein folding (GO:00064582)",
       'posttranslational protein folding (GO:0051087)',"'de novo' protein folding (GO:00064583)",
       'posttranslational protein folding (GO:00510844)',"'de novo' protein folding (GO:00064588)",
       'posttranslational protein folding (GO:00510855)',"'de novo' protein folding (GO:00064511)",
       'posttranslational protein folding (GO:00510866)',"'de novo' protein folding (GO:000645822)",
       'posttranslational protein folding (GO:00510877)',"'de novo' protein folding (GO:000645833)")

FE<-c(5,10,15,20,25,35,10,15,5,10,15,20,25,35,10,15)
FDR<-c(76,23,45,67,56,45,78,34,76,23,45,67,56,45,78,34)
d<-data.frame(BIO,FE,FDR,stringsAsFactors = F)

# Libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


# Most basic bubble plot
d %>%
  arrange(desc(FDR)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=FE, y=BIO, size=FE, color=FDR)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(NA,50))+
  geom_point(alpha=0.5) +
  scale_size(range = c(.1, 24), name="Population (M)")
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see now you have more space. If you are exporting the plot to `.png` for example, the same dimensions will be kept, just be careful of using proper `width` and `height` values in `ggsave()`.

Comment: I like your answer but what if the x axis xas really samll values like in the edit.

Comment: @firmo23 In such case you can enable `breaks` option for `scale_x_continuous` and you can define n breaks that will expand the axis despite how small values are. Did you edited the question? I ran your code again and obtained same results!

Comment: I will accept your answer since it fits with the original Q and create a new Q

Answer (score 0):

The culprit appears to be the first entry in `BIO`. Is it really meant to have `posttranslational protein folding (GO:0051084)` repeated twice? If you clean your data labels, then you can get a plot that is wider with less space dedicated to the y axis label (because the unusually long label is fixed).

```
BIO<-c('posttranslational protein folding (GO:0051084)',"'de novo' protein folding (GO:0006458)",
       'posttranslational protein folding (GO:0051085)',"'de novo' protein folding (GO:0006451)",
       'posttranslational protein folding (GO:0051086)',"'de novo' protein folding (GO:00064582)",
       'posttranslational protein folding (GO:0051087)',"'de novo' protein folding (GO:00064583)",
       'posttranslational protein folding (GO:00510844)',"'de novo' protein folding (GO:00064588)",
       'posttranslational protein folding (GO:00510855)',"'de novo' protein folding (GO:00064511)",
       'posttranslational protein folding (GO:00510866)',"'de novo' protein folding (GO:000645822)",
       'posttranslational protein folding (GO:00510877)',"'de novo' protein folding (GO:000645833)")
```

[image]